# How to import contacts from social networking websites using Grails?

Tags: grails, social-networking

I am trying to import contacts from social networking websites and wanted to save into database.

I searched and found the plugin `compile ":inviter:0.4"`, but when I added it to my build config, it gave me an error.

Is their any alternative option to import contacts from social websites like Facebook, Twitter, Google+ or LinkedIn?

Comment: You have used `grails oauth plugin`, why you don't go with that, you just need the URL from which service provider send back contacts. I have published a demo @http://grailsoauthplugindemo.herokuapp.com (first login with facebook then use navbar link down arrow image) with Facebook using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`.

Comment: @user1690588 : Thank you reply. Actually i am trying to do that User can select which facebook or other social websites friends invites.. and those selected user i wanted to save in my database

Comment: like twitter do. twitter ask us to import gmail contact and then after allowing its gives us to friend list .. after selecting a particular user .. twitter send a invitation email to selected users